# jQuery - Function to Append to Variable

Tags: jquery, variables, sharepoint, var

My Intent: Use jQuery script interfaced with SharePoint services to query a SharePoint list and return two fields (Name and URL) for each item so I can populate a search bar with the vendors where when clicked takes you to the items details.

Issue: I don't know enough about jQuery variables to understand how to add to the required variable structure. Below is an example of what I **need** my variable to look like:

**Vendors Variable Example**

```
$(function(){
    var vendors = [
        { value: 'Google', url: 'http://www.google.com' },
        { value: 'Google News', url: 'http://www.news.google.com' },
];
```

My SharePoint query iterates through each results from the CAML Query and populates a 'name' variable and an 'URL' variable with the data I need.

**Query Result Example**

```
//get the title field (Vendor Name)
var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));

//get the id field (ID)
var url = ($(this).attr("ows_URL"));
```

What would a function look like that took the data from my Query Result Example and for each iteration added the vendor and url to the vendors variable (see Vendors Variable Example)?

Thanks,

Gwb1231

Comment: I may be misunderstanding your question, but is there something preventing you from just appending the values directly to the `vendors` array like so? `vendors.push({ value: $(this).attr("ows_Title"), url: $(this).attr("ows_URL") });`

Comment: Hey @Thriggle,  I figured something like that was possible but was not sure how to accomplish it. I used your code as a basis and it worked wonderfully. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Initialize `vendors=[]` before iteration

During the iteration of each result,put the below code

```
var name = ($(this).attr("ows_Title"));
var url = ($(this).attr("ows_URL"));
vendors.push({ value: name, url: url });
```

After iteration,the results will be stored in **vendors array.**